# Can Xamarin read httponly cookies?

Tags: xamarin, cookie-httponly

Question is more or less in the title. I've googled and googled to no avail.
Unfortunately I can not try it out myself for a few more days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can. I can make a request using `HttpClient` to an endpoint with a `CookieContainer` attached to my `HttpClientHandler` and when I get the response back I can look in the `HttpClientHandler` instance's `CookieContainer` and the cookie is there.

I have had god awful trouble with cookies but it usually ends up being an issue with using the correct domain. Everything has been working for me now for a while, so it is definitely possible.

Comment: Great. But I must check this. Are you positive that you can read data from cookie that is sent to you as httponly cookie. I don't see why not, after all xamarin isn't a browser, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Comment: @MarkoJovanović I just double checked and I am positive.